# Non-reflexivity of $B(\mathbb H)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

How does one prove that the space $B(\mathbb H)$ of bounded operators on a infinite dimensional (separable) Hilbert space is **not** reflexive?

I guess this should go along the lines of the non-reflexivity of $l_\infty$, but I was unable to find this written down somewhere.

Comment: Why do you know that it is not reflexive, if you don't have a proof?

Comment: This question is probably too elementary for MO. Let me just give a hint: reflexivity passes to subspaces and the subspace of diagonal operators (with respect to some orthonormal basis) is isomorphic to $\ell_{\infty}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be a good idea to extend my comment to an answer.

First of all, pick any orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{H}$ so that $B(\mathbb{H})$ can be identified with $B(\ell_2)$. The subspace of diagonal operators is clearly isometric to $\ell_{\infty}$. It is a general truth that if $Y$ is a closed subspace of a reflexive Banach space $X$ then $Y$ is reflexive itself; e.g. its unit ball is weakly compact. It means that $B(\mathbb{H})$ cannot be reflexive.

Another route, already suggested by **Marc Palm**, is to use the fact that the reflexivity of $X$ is equivalent to the reflexivity of $X^{\ast}$. Since $(K(\ell_2))^{\ast\ast}$ (bidual of the space of compact operators) is isometric to $B(\ell_2)$, the reflexivity of $B(\ell_2)$ would imply that $K(\ell_2)$ is isomorphic to $B(\ell_2)$; the former space is separable, so it is not possible.

Answer (score 4):

The predual of $B(H)$ are the trace class operators. It is a general result that if $X$ is not isomorphic to $X^{**}$ via the canonical embedding, so is $X^{*}$ not isomorphic to $X^{***}$ via the canonical embedding. The last fact is an exercise in Simon-Reed Mathematical Prinicple of Physics Vol 1.